# In Unity, why is adding a Vector2 and a Vector3 ambiguous but assigning isn't?

Tags: c#, unity, 2d, 3d, vector

Given the following two vectors:

```
Vector3 v3 = Vector3.one;
Vector2 v2 = Vector2.one;
```

This line is ambiguous:

```
v3 += v2; // Unity reports dimension ambiguity
```

whilst this assignment isn't:

```
v3 = v2; // Unity assigns despite different dimensions
```

Why is this?

Comment: So, thank you very much to Anko and Xavi Montero for the great answers. Trying to reproduce the problem I realized my question should be changed. The fact is happening when assigning a Vector2 to transform.position so that
transform.position = a + b;
where BOTH a and b are Vector2 compiles correctly and it assigns x and y!
Instead, it doesn't work when I change the line to
transform.position += a; // or b
I'm using Unity 5.0.0f and the script is attached to a UI element (Image) which doesn't affect the compiler but may be important information for you to reproduce the scenario.

Comment: So you guys tell me what to do. Shall we change the question and your answers accordingly or shall we start a new one?

Comment: Vector3 + Vector2 and Vector3 += Vector2 will never work no matter what you want because both can be implicitly converted to the other one and you need to explicitly cast according to what you want to do. Vector3 = Vector2 works because there's no ambiguity. I don't see the need to change or post a new question.

Comment: I'm saying to change the question because the case is slightly different from what I described, which might brake the flow of your answer.

Comment: Nah don't worry, nothing breaks.

Comment: Ok. Question changed, not too much hopefully, but this is the case.

Comment: Added a small edit to the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Full issue message:

> error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `UnityEngine.Vector2.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.Vector2)' and`UnityEngine.Vector3.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)'

Unity provided a way to implicitly convert a `Vector3` to a `Vector2` and vice-versa. This causes an ambiguity in your case because both + operators can be applied.

Cast your `Vector2` to a `Vector3` explicitly in that operation, so that the compiler knows to use `UnityEngine.Vector3.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)`.

If you're curious, Microsoft's docs for that specific error are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky5f1hz8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

---

Edit after your edit:

`Vec3 += Vec2` is ambiguous for the same reason described above. Imagine `Vec3 += Vec2` being in fact `Vec3 = Vec3 + Vec2`. `Vec3 + Vec2` can yield both `Vector2` and `Vector3` as answer due to implicit conversions, that's why you have to specify what you want.

`Vec3 = Vec2` is not ambiguous because Vec2 is implicitly converted to a `Vector3` and then assigned to the initial Vec3. So the whole operation is really `Vector3 = Vector3` without you having to cast Vec2 to a `Vector3` manually.

Comment: So Unity assumes I want my Vector3's x and y to be assigned from my Vector2's x and y and my z set to 0f. Right?

Comment: Yes, imagine Vec3 = Vec2 being equivalent to Vec3 = (Vector3)Vec2. You don't need to cast manually because it can't really be anything other than that in that case.

Comment: Yeah, actually my question could be titled something like "Why don't I need to cast to Vector3 when assigning a Vector2". I'm not the best in titling and crafting perfect questions :/
Thank you Alex. My curiosity has been (over)satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

Let me rename the vars (for clarity):

```
Vector3 pos3d = new Vector3 (1f, 2f, 3f);
Vector2 pos2d = new Vector2 (1f, 2f);
```

### Answer

It is because of the section `pos3d + pos2d` of the line. This part is really ambiguous while the `+=` is not. Let me clarify why one and why the other.

### Analysis 1

In this line

```
transform.position = pos3d + pos2d;
```

the compiler first tries to evaluate the expression `pos3d + pos2d` before proceeding, regardless of where the result is going to be placed.

To do so, the system first tries to find any public static function that adds a Vector3 plus a Vector2, for example this possible signature:

```
public static Vector3 operator +(Vector3 a, Vector2 b);
```

or for example this possible signature:

```
public static Vector2 operator +(Vector3 a, Vector2 b);
```

Nevertheless there is not any of those signatures in the API so the compiler tries to "cast" parameters to known signatures.

Then the compiler finds those two potential signatures:

```
public static Vector3 operator +(Vector3 a, Vector3 b);
public static Vector2 operator +(Vector2 a, Vector2 b);
```

These are documented here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_add.html
and here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_add.html

So there are two possibilities:

So as both castings are possible, pos2d can be casted to a Vector3 and pos3d is castabale into a Vector2, the compiler then finds to possible ways to compile the same source code (provided automatic hidden castings are in place).

It is either possible to cast pos3d into Vector2 and proceed with the second signature, or either cast pos2d into Vector3 and proceed with the first signature.

As the expression `pos3d + pos2d` is evaluated first, before taking in consideration "where the result will be applied" then the compiler does not know what cast would you -as coder- like it to perform.

If you want to move towards 3D, you can write this:

```
transform.position = pos3d + ( Vector3 )pos2d;
```

and the problem is gone, as now it is clear: first move pos2d into another object of type Vector3, then do the sum of Vector3 + Vector3. Provided that there is this static signature

```
public static Vector3 operator +(Vector3 a, Vector3 b);
```

available, that one will be used with no ambiguity at all.

### Analysis 2

On the other hand, when you do

```
transform.position = pos3d;
transform.position += pos2d;
```

there is no ambiguity: The first line assigns a Vector3 into a Vector3 (no doubts).

The second line is equivalent to

```
transform.position = transform.position + pos2d;
```

with the particularity the transform.position is only evaluated once, and therefore the type is taken in consideration, as you can see in this Microsoft page about the `+=` operator:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx

It in addition says "The += operator cannot be overloaded directly, but user-defined types can overload the + operator (see operator)." so we should think the `Vector3`'s `+=` operator acts as described by microsoft where it says:

> ```
> x += y
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> x = x + y
> ```
>
> except that x is only evaluated once. The meaning of the + operator
>   depends on the types of x and y (addition for numeric operands,
>   concatenation for string operands, and so forth).

so we can be sure the second approach invokes the + operand of the `Vector3` class, which has the signature:

```
public static Vector3 operator +(Vector3 a, Vector3 b);
```

so there is not any other way to achieve this than converting the pos2d into a Vector3 thanks to an implicit hidden cast that cannot be of any other form.

Hope to help!!

---

Edit

In `Unity 5.0.1f1 Personal` with `MonoDevelop-Unit 4.0.1`, as Alex M. says, the lines:

```
transform.position = pos3d;
transform.position += pos2d;
```

still cast the error `"Assets/Scripts/CubeScript.cs(15,27): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'UnityEngine.Vector2.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.Vector2)' and 'UnityEngine.Vector3.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)'"`

so really the += is using both signatures

```
public static Vector3 operator +(Vector3 a, Vector3 b);
public static Vector2 operator +(Vector2 a, Vector2 b);
```

regardless of the fact of already knowing "where" the result shall be placed (I guess because outputting a Vector2 is castable to the destination (Vector3) and if that cast was not possible probably, maybe, the compiler would choose the one with the proper output type).

Thanks for the point Alex M.

Comment: `+=` doesn't work either, it's still a `Vector3` + `Vector2`. See my answer.

Comment: Right, upvoted yours, shall edit mine.

Comment: Just edited to incorporate your comment.

Comment: transform.position += pos2d is compiling. I'll be more precise tomorrow (might be just a version bug)

Comment: After the edits I got lost in the sequence... so... `pos3d += pos2d` (as per your edited question) fails but `transform.position += pos2d` compiles (as per your comment above)?? Would seem weird as `.position` is `Vector3` - Can't clearly see if that's what you are meaning.